# How can I only publish a collection when needed?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

In my application I have a public profile, that is just a subset of all the fields available for my Meteor.users. I know I can just publish certain fields from the collection, but I feel like when I subscribe to that data, that's a lot of unnecessary data being transferred to the user. So, I want to be able to just publish this data when the user requests it, i.e. when you visit `/public-profile/425f7834985r79na8syf`

Comment: Search for route/template level subscriptions.

Comment: Do you have some router code? As currently written it is quite unclear what you want to achieve exactly. @MasterAM gave some good directions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Define a route that takes a parameter (in your case `/public-profile/:_id`)
2. Have your route subscribe to a publication using that `_id` as an argument to the subscription, ex:

   ```
   Meteor.subscribe('oneProfile',id);
   ```
3. Setup your publication as:

   ```
   Meteor.publish('oneProfile',function(id){
     return Meteor.users.find({_id: id},{fields: {thisField: 1, thatField: 1}});
   });
   ```

Note that this publish function is returning a *cursor* even though we only expect a single document. Publish functions cannot return a single document using `findOne()`.

Comment: Once I get back that cursor, how can I make it into something I can work with on the client side?

Comment: Assuming you are using iron-router, then simply return the object in your `data` function with `data: function(){ return Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.params._id}); }`

Comment: Are you sure that works? I have that in my code and it's erroring (I think because it tries to return the `Meteor.users` user before it has been published to the client. I also have the `waitOn` function `return Meteor.subscribe('myCollection')`

Comment: `waitOn` should handle waiting for the subscription to be ready. What's the error?